# How can I achieve this kind of sea-wave progress in android (check this gif image)?

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

I want to add the progress wave like the above gif image. I've seen this kind of progress wave recently in many apps. I also searched for the 3rd party library but couldn't find one. Maybe there is one, but I'm not searching with correct keywords.

Comment: Are you talking about that blank card waves ?

Comment: I don't know what this kind of effect called that's why I've added the gif image.

Comment: This is called shimmering effects. I had posted an answer to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Loading list place holders, you can use Shimmering Animations. I am listing out some of the cool Third parties libraries which you can use.

- https://github.com/facebook/shimmer-android
- https://github.com/team-supercharge/ShimmerLayout

Here is one of the best tutorial link

https://www.androidhive.info/2018/01/android-content-placeholder-animation-like-facebook-using-shimmer/